# In SQL How to get the LeaveType depends upon today date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table call Trn_EmployeeLeave How to get the Status depends upon todays date?

The Data Look Like

```
EmpNo   start       End         Type
1      09-Jun-15    30-Jun-15   Justified
1      01-Jul-15    19-Aug-15   Sick Leave
1     20-Aug-15    20-Sep-15    Annual
```

Means suppose todays date in between 09-Jun-15 to 30-Jun-2015 then i will get the status "Justified" its depends on Todays date.

Please help on this.
Thanks
Basit.

Comment: What SQL have you tried already?  This does not seem like it will be a difficult piece of SQL

Comment: Examples of `BETWEEN` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx

Comment: Dear thanks, SELECT * from Trn_EmployeeLeave Where EmpNo=1 and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN '2015-06-09' AND '2015-06-30' but how to get start and end dates? It means if there is today date then check it in sql query this date in which date slab and shows the status

Comment: SELECT * from Trn_EmployeeLeave As el Where EmpNo=1 and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN el.Start AND el.end

Comment: Osome Perfect. Thanks Mihir

Answer (score 0):

**MS SQL**

suppose you want to get data from Trn_EmployeeLeave table

```
SELECT EmpNo,start,End,'Justified' Type
FROM Trn_EmployeeLeave
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN start AND End;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CURDATE()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp) for getting today's date. And [Between](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) can be used to find if a date/number lies in a range:
    select Type from Trm_EmployeeLeave where curdate() BETWEEN start AND end;

Or you simply use greater than and less than operators

```
select Type from Trm_EmployeeLeave where start <= curdate() AND end >= curdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` like this

```
SELECT EmpNo,start,End,
CASE
    WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN startd AND end 
    THEN 'Justified'
    WHEN --Other conditions THEN 'Sick Leave' ELSE 'Annual' END AS Type
FROM Trn_EmployeeLeave
```